# Inserting values into a table by iterating another

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying the following on an ORACLE database

I have a table (t1) with a list of values

```
id        name
1          A
2          B
3          C
4          C
5          B
6          A
7          A
8          D
```

I created a new table into which I want to add the unique names from t1, while using a sequence to add the ID

```
create sequence t2_seq start with 100 increment by 1;
CREATE TABLE t2 (
    id_t2 NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    name_t2 VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```

I tried the following, but am unsure why it's not working

```
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (t2_seq.nextval, name) SELECT DISTINCT name FROM t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, but it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO t2  (id_t2, name_t2) 
    SELECT t2_seq.nextval, name
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name
          FROM (SELECT 'a' as name FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'a' FROM DUAl UNION ALL SELECT 'b' FROM DUAL)
         ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a878828eba4c8d128eb3b6ca217a709) is a db<>fiddle.

However, in the most recent versions of Oracle, you don't need a sequence for this.  You can use:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
    id_t2 NUMBER(5) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name_t2 VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```